# Google Maps with night view?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to use with google api v3 something similar to this: https://earthbuilder.google.com/10446176163891957399-13737975182519107424-4/mapview/

Should I use google map engine to apply the night view overlay?

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

The link no longer works, but assuming you want something like Google Maps' "night mode" (that automatically activates when navigating during night), yes, it's possible!

You need to use map styling, as described in [this official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/styling).

> With style options you can customize the presentation of the standard Google map styles, changing the visual display of features like roads, parks, businesses, and other points of interest. This means that you can emphasize particular components of the map or make the map complement the style of your app.
>
> (...)
>
> To style your map, call [`GoogleMap.setMapStyle()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMapStyle(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions)) passing a [`MapStyleOptions`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MapStyleOptions) object that contains your style declarations in JSON format.

You can use the [Maps Platform Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) as a quick way to generate a JSON styling object.